# how to make this program run faster?

Tags: c++

I'm always getting around `12 ms` I want to get around `5ms`. 
How can I achieve this? 
Does using an iterator make a program run faster?

```
class Solution {
public:
    int singleNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
        // for (int i = 1; i < nums.size(); i++) {
        //     nums[0] ^= nums[i];
        // }
        // return nums[0];

        for (auto i = nums.begin() + 1; i < nums.end(); ++i) {
            nums[0] ^= *i;
        }
        return nums[0];
    }
};
```

Comment: @S.M.I think this is a problem from LeetCode, all you need to do is implement the function inside the class

Comment: How do you know that the ideal solution can run in 5 ms?

Comment: How do I implement the function inside the class. Do you mean to implement it as private?

Comment: From leetcode. @Wander3r

Comment: There really isn't much you can do to speed up what you have, and definitely not by almost 2.5:1. There must be a different algorithm you can use to eliminate most of the of the work.

Comment: With online challenges, TLE problems usually are solved by calculating instead of simulating. For helping with that, more information is needed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I pasted both versions into [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zLPWgb). The differences of generated machine code are small but the index version seems to have one additional `mov` (I spotted on the first glance). However, this is probably not what may you save 7 of 12 ms. I think there is less what you can do in fine-grain. A completely different algorithm may save you the time - or it's just possible only with a faster CPU or a better compiler. (About the latter, I don't have much hope. The g++ 9.3 is currently not that bad among what's available.)

Comment: Have you turned on all optimizations (-O3 on the compiler)? You could use a 64-bit variable for XORing 2 items at a time and at the end of the loop combine the two ints. You could use SIMD instructions, you could use multi-threading

Comment: `Does using an iterator make a program run faster?` Maybe yes, maybe no, maybe no difference. Iterators were not designed with efficiency in mind (rather they were designed to allow different types of container to be treated in a consistent manner) So there's no reason to think that  they would be any better or any worse than anything else. If you want answers then write the code and time it.

Comment: @Sebastian If this is checked on an online facility, he probably hasn't control over this.

Comment: @Scheff It seems always with these online challenges the trick is a better algorithm, not micro-optimising the obvious implementation

Comment: @Scheff I expected to see about the same on both cases and was surprised by the amount of differences. clang was particularly interesting. It looks like it did a lot of loop-unrolling.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, that's a nice and tempting little example to fiddle with what the compilers do or do not in comparison. But actually, I'm with Yunnosch and John. ;-)

Comment: You can add me onto that list, @Scheff . You can tune that loop six ways from Sunday and you'll never get a 2:5 times performance improvement.

Comment: One might also consider trying loop unrolling.

Answer (score 6):

Discarding access `nums[0]` in the loop, makes tests 5x faster.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int singleNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
        int r = nums[0];
        for (auto i = nums.begin() + 1; i < nums.end(); ++i) {
            r ^= *i;
        }
        nums[0] = r;
        return r;
    }
};
```

http://quick-bench.com/w0-RRDzLq9RF-tbLjdSS2omgyGM

The performance is better because of `int r` stored in one of the CPU registers. If you try `int& r = nums[0];`, the performance is the same as OP's origin one.

---

I have looked at [Blastfurnace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60998325/6752050). It seems the compiler optimizes code better if the whole vector is iterated. So the solution bellow is even 7x faster than OP's original one.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int singleNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
        int r = 0;
        for (auto i = nums.begin(); i < nums.end(); ++i) {
            r ^= *i;
        }
        nums[0] = r;
        return r;
    }
};
```

And the final 7x faster and shorter solution if range-for-loop used

```
class Solution {
public:
    int singleNumber1(std::vector<int>& nums) {
        int r = 0;
        for (const int i : nums) {
            r ^= i;
        }
        nums[0] = r;
        return r;
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm stunned that the compiler didn't do this.

Comment: If this helped, then not accessing `nums.end()` might help, too.

Comment: fwiw using iterators or not does not seem to make any difference: http://quick-bench.com/T31hkHUvFx5CaHrpxmmLz0U7o5E

Comment: Good, what a relief.

Comment: using long long int improved this only for -O1 or less, with -O3 and long long int only a tiny further improvement was possible

Answer (score 2):

I modified the code in [S.M.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60986523/445976) by replacing the `for` loop with a call to [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate). Quickbench showed an additional 1.4x speedup over the hand-rolled loop.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int singleNumber(std::vector<int>& nums) {
        int r = std::accumulate(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0, std::bit_xor<int>());
        nums[0] = r; // is this necessary?
        return r;
    }
};
```

http://quick-bench.com/8dnWzm3o4l2m7p3zXM-8FmxH97I

Comment: Does the accumulate function start with element 1 (not 0)?

Comment: @Sebastian This code iterates over every element of the vector. The initial value for the operation is `0`, the third parameter of the function call. It does do the same work as the code in the question.

Comment: @Sebastian it starts from the element `nums[0]` and the initial value 0. So after `0 ^ nums[0]` is processed, it continues like starting from the element `nums[1]` and the initial value `nums[0]` as in OP's question.

Comment: @Sebastian It could be rewritten as `std::accumulate(nums.begin() + 1, nums.end(), nums[0], std::bit_xor<int>());` but I find that kind of ugly and if the vector was **empty** it would be a bug.